# Yii system params from database. Yii::app()->getParams() not giving results

Tags: php, yii

I have extended CWebApplication as following to add params (Application-level parameters) from database. but as of now, i dont get anything when i try to retrieve params using

```
echo Yii::app()->params['adminMobileNo'];
```

extended code,

```
class QelasyApplication extends CWebApplication
{
    const PARAM_CACHE = 'params';

    public function setParams($value)
    {
        echo 'test 1';
        exit;
        $params = parent::getParams();
        print_r($params);
        echo 'test 2';
        exit;

        $value = Yii::app()->cache->get(self::PARAM_CACHE);
        if ($value === false) {
            $model = new SystemParam();
            $value = $model->getParam();
            print_r($value);
            echo 'test 3';
            exit;
            Yii::app()->cache->add(self::PARAM_CACHE, $value, 1800);
        }

        foreach ($value as $k => $v)
            $params->add($k, $v);
    }
}
```

in the main index.php

```
require_once($yii);
require_once($protected.'components/QelasyApplication.php');
$application = new QelasyApplication($config);
$application->run();
```

and in a controller, i am trying to access the params as

```
        Yii::app()->params['abc'] = 123;
        echo Yii::app()->params['basePath'];
        echo Yii::app()->params['abc'];
        echo Yii::app()->params['adminMobileNo'];
//        print_r(Yii::app()->getParams());
exit;
```

but no output it just exits.

even the setParams method isnt running, coz the echo statements inside are not displayed. what could be the reason ?

this is the output i get,

```
 CAttributeCollection#1
(
    [caseSensitive] => true
    [CMap:_d] => array()
    [CMap:_r] => false
    [CComponent:_e] => null
    [CComponent:_m] => null
)
```

Params.php approach

```
$params = Yii::app()->getParams();
$value = Yii::app()->cache->get(self::PARAM_CACHE);

if ($value === false) {
    $model = new SystemParam();
    $value = $model->getParam();
    Yii::app()->cache->add(self::PARAM_CACHE, $value, 1800);
}

foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    $params->add($k, $v);
```

still i am unable to get it work with `Yii::app()->cache->get(self::PARAM_CACHE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the following in main.php worked. (empty array)

```
'params' => array(),
```

This is with first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create `params.php` in `config` folder. Create your param array from db and return it. Then in your

```
protected/config/main.php
```

add

```
...
'params' => require('params.php'),
...
```

The you will be able to access them as:

```
 Yii::app()->params['YOUR_PARAM_KEY'];
```

Comment: i added, but it says Warning: require(params.php): failed to open stream:

Comment: Sorry my mistake put `params.php` file in `protected/config/` folder not in `components` folder. means put it in the same folder as `main.php` it will work :)

Comment: it does not seem to be a good practice.. is there any better way ? or to sort out my approach as mentioned above.